# How to run shared angular code in visual studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I am learning angular. I have got an angular code I need to work on. I copied the src folder and package file in my visual studio web project, restored dependencies, build using npm start and i am able to open application pages at localhost://4200. 
But when I build the project in visual studio and run using F5, blank index.html page loads and no error is shown in developers console

How to run project in visual studio?
Do I need to setup some scripts to run it in visual studio? 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I wish if you would have googled it, before asking here. Anyways try this [How to create an Angular 4 app with Visual Studio 2017](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-4-app-with-visual-studio-2017/)

OR you may also try this [How to build an Angular Application with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2017, visualized](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa)

Comment: I tried searching on net, but could not able to make it run in visual studio. I will try your links as well. 
Thanks for your response Prakash.